# Return value from function that contain a Dialog

Tags: android, function, dialog

There is a Function that contains a Dialog of the list of items,

problem is that when I open dialog it returns "false", but it does not return anything when I select an item of dialog

```
 private boolean selectShopType(String subServiceId, String isRemove) {

    final boolean[] isAddedToCart = {false};
    String[] type = {"At shop", "At home"};
    AlertDialog.Builder stateDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_list, null);
    stateDialog.setView(convertView);
    stateDialog.setTitle("Select type");
    final AlertDialog dialog = stateDialog.show();
    ListView stateList = convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, type);
    stateList.setAdapter(adapter);
    stateList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            if (position == 0) {
                addToCart(subServiceId, "1");
            } else {
                addToCart(subServiceId, "2");
            }
            isAddedToCart[0] = true;
           dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    return isAddedToCart[0];

}
```

//call selectShopType

```
return selectShopType(subServiceId, isRemove);
```

Comment: Pretty normal behaviour. The function selectShopType launches the dialog and then returns as you have seen. Much later the user can click a button. The onItemClick function is a void function so returns nothing.

Comment: Add a callback parameter to `selectShopType()` and call that callback when the user selects something in the dialog.